# vb6 Treeview1 Question Add Status to For Statement

Tags: vb6

This `For` statement I want to add a status to let me know it has completed at this line shown below in code.

```vb
Private Sub Command21_Click()
    Dim NodX As Node
    Dim NodX2 As Node
    Dim ii As Integer
    Dim iCounter As Integer

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each NodX In TreeView1.Nodes
        ii = NodX.Index
        If NodX.Image = 4 Then
            ' Check for Children
            If NodX.Children > 0 Then
                ' Get first Child
                Set NodX2 = NodX.Child
                ' Loop through all children
                For iCounter = 1 To NodX.Children
                    ' Set image to 3 if it was 5
                    If NodX2.Image = 5 And NodX2.Parent.Image = 4 Then
                        NodX2.Image = 3
                    End If    

                    'If NodX2.Image = 3 And NodX2.Parent.Image = 4 Then NodX2.Parent.Image = 9
                    ' Get next node
                    Set NodX2 = NodX2.Next
                Next
            End If
            If TreeView1.Nodes(NodX2.Index).Index = TreeView1.Nodes.Count - 0 Then
                'Label3.Caption = "done"
                'Call Command5_Click
                'Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

were you see `NodX2.Image = 3` I need to add some code here to let me know it has completed adding all that so `label3.caption = "done"`.

Comment: Why can't you just add `label3.caption = "done"` at the end of the Sub, just after the last `Next`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `label3.caption = "done"` at the end of the Sub, just after the last `Next`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Command21_Click()
    Dim NodX As Node
    Dim NodX2 As Node
    Dim ii As Integer
    Dim iCounter As Integer

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each NodX In TreeView1.Nodes
        ii = NodX.Index
        If NodX.Image = 4 Then
            ' Check for Children
            If NodX.Children > 0 Then
                ' Get first Child
                Set NodX2 = NodX.Child
                ' Loop through all children
                For iCounter = 1 To NodX.Children
                    ' Set image to 3 if it was 5
                    If NodX2.Image = 5 And NodX2.Parent.Image = 4 Then
                        NodX2.Image = 3
                    End If    

                    'If NodX2.Image = 3 And NodX2.Parent.Image = 4 Then NodX2.Parent.Image = 9
                    ' Get next node
                    Set NodX2 = NodX2.Next
                Next
            End If
            If TreeView1.Nodes(NodX2.Index).Index = TreeView1.Nodes.Count - 0 Then
                'Label3.Caption = "done"
                'Call Command5_Click
                'Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
Call Command5_Click
End Sub
```

big thanks to **

### Étienne Laneville

**